# Is the term "handle" reserved in PHP?

Tags: php

In my php code, I am writing a class to create log files, and therefore have to work with files. I would like to store the variable $handle as a field, however when I refer to it as $this->handle, "handle" changes color, to indicate that perhaps it is a reserved term.

I looked through the php manual as well as some other online sources and haven't found anywhere saying it is actually reserved. Can someone clear this up for me?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers!

------------- Edit ---------------

[image: Getting closer...Screenshot taken from BBEdit, with file extension of .php]

It looks like it's recognizing handle as at least 3 static methods...still not sure what the "K" word means. Key?

[image: Screen shot of the actual class that I am using the code in]

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as a reserved object property name. What were you concerned about specifically? Example?

Comment: *"I looked through the manual"* ... strange, because when I google "php reserved words" the first result I get is the PHP manual entry for [**List of Reserved Words**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php)

Comment: @rdlowrey yeah. I looked through that list, and each link inside of it. Didn't find anything about "handle". Sorry, I should have been more specific.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I doubt the "handle" term is a reserved object property name as well, I don't think it is that – perhaps the term referred to some pre-defined PHP function, or maybe it's just my text editor that is coloring "handle" the same color as other PHP reserved words, such as "echo" or "print", and words that are pre-defined. However, when I tried to execute the script using $this->handle, where handle was my a field name of my class, I didn't get any output. That leads me to believe that "handle" is a reserved term, but I can't find any sources to verify it :]

Comment: @fettereddingoskidney: You're asking the wrong question then. Check this out for example: http://codepad.org/feCLLRjB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is it not reserved, but it is a common convention to call resource IDs and more `$handle`. In fact, you can find it throughout the PHP documentation. For example, [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: I definitely agree that it is a common convention to use $handle, but that is a variable name. I am familiar with the fopen documentation and the use of $handle, but not sure why "handle" alone, without the "$" would be colored – can you provide another resource, by any chance? Thanks for your help :]

Comment: I think he's asking about class property names, not variable names. The only reserved variable name I can think of is `$this`. Even superglobals are writable and can be unset, etc.

Comment: well, I'm not necessarily only asking about class property names. Sorry for not being clear on that point...I was just explaining the use of handle in the context of my code (which is in a class). I have tried using "handle" in static PHP, outside of a class, and I get the same result.

Comment: @ john conde yeah, it appears that the word is reserved, according to BBEdit...still can't find any documentation though :/. Thanks for the help, all.

Comment: It just may be a case of BBEdit highlighting it because it recognizes it as being a commonly used word as opposed to it really being reserved.

Comment: I use Notepad++ and it unnecessarily highlights keywords sometimes, like `$this->class`.

Comment: Check out SOAP Server handle function which is why i am here.... https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.handle.php